# What is the process "pool_workqueue_release"?

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, process, process-management

What is pool_workqueue_release?

It seems it's spawned right after kthreadd, ktrheadd is the main process/daemon to create kernel threads, right?

In linux/kernel/workqueue.c I found:

```
static void __init wq_cpu_intensive_thresh_init(void)
{
    unsigned long thresh;
    unsigned long bogo;

    pwq_release_worker = kthread_create_worker(0, "pool_workqueue_release");
    BUG_ON(IS_ERR(pwq_release_worker));
```